# Uncaught SystaxError while sending JSONArray converted to String as parameter in Parse Cloud Function

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

*TL:DR; How do I send JSONArray as parameter in Parse Cloud Functions?*

I'm requesting a Parse Cloud Function. Whenever I try to convert JSONArray to String and send as params, I get this exception

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in <unknown file>:1
```

Below is my code, this is the same as given in sample code in Parse Guide:

```
// create a JSONObject
JSONObject singleJsonObj= new JSONObject();
singleJsonObj.put("time", "2017-01-01T06:00:00Z");
singleJsonObj.put("title", "Adib");
singleJsonObj.put("profile", "AbCdIj76");

// add JSONObject to JSONArray
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(singleJsonObj);

// put as parameter
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("form", formId);
params.put("records", jsonArray.toString());

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("someFunctionName", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Float object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // Yay!
        } else {
            // Damn!!
        }
    }
});
```

If I don't send it as String, it shows another error as **InvalidArgumentException: Invalid type for ParseObject: JSONArray**. I haven't found any official documentation on how to send JSONArray as parameter in Parse Cloud Function.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple overloaded version of callFunctionInBackground. If its a cloud function you should use this one: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/Parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseCloud.java#L17

And define the callback as: new FunctionCallback()

Hope it helps.